# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF parse@[native code] in Unity WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, browser-cache, unity-webgl

This question is specifically related to Unity WebGL builds. It happens sometimes after updating the build files on the server - although not every time and seems more frequent in Safari.

Clearing the cache resolves the issue, but it would be a pain to ask users to clear cache after every update.

I have removed Unity's Data Caching option in the build settings and also tried switching between Brotli and Gzip.

Comment: Is this only happening after you modified something? In that case a cashing issue might not have too much impact on your users since later on you probably do not expect this to change all the time. In general I would suggest to turn of caching on your server side and only cache performance relevant parts (such as meshes, textures etc)

Comment: Yes only when there is an update. Thanks I will look into turning off caching on the server side